# Alternative solution to ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=b$$ where $a,b$ are constants. I know how to solve this using the integration factor just multiply the equation by $e^{at}$ and we are essentially done. However we were told in class that this is possible with separation of variables. Can someone show me how? I just do not see it.

Thank you!

Comment: With Separation of Variables , we have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{-a y + b} ~ dy = \int dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note

$$\frac{dy}{b-ay}=dt$$